# How to trigger a link in a tab of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, triggers, anchor

When a user is on the home page, he can click on a link that redirects him to another page (so far, it works).
In the new page, I would like the link to automatically open the second tab of a table by doing an "auto click" (trigger).

The link of the home page is specific (it has an anchor).
I managed to make a script that works, the problem is that if I open this page from the navigation menu, the second tab of the table still opens.

I would like that only the specific link can automatically open the second tab of the table.

[Landing Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSvFM.png)
[Service Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOQtR.jpg)

Here is the code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        console.log('clicked');
       });
     // set time out 5 sec
        setTimeout(function(){
           $('.et_pb_tab_3 > a').trigger('click');
       }, 500);
       console.log('triggered');
   });
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Best regards,

Johann

Comment: There are various techniques for doing this sort of thing. For instance you can add a `#tab-2` hash value to your url, and then read the `location.hash` when the new page is loading, to determine which tab to open. You could also use something more fancy like [History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)...wouldn't show in the url if you use the state object...but would also be more complex and a lot more work to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it was easy and i'd like to thanks @Branson Smith for inspiration.

i just had i conditional statement to check if there is a hash in the url :

```
if (window.location.hash == '#myHash') {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myID').click(function(){
            console.log('clicked');
           });
            setTimeout(function(){
               $('.myClass > a').trigger('click');
           }, 2000);
           console.log('triggered');
       });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A url parameter may get the job done for you. From the link you want to open you could do something like: `example-link.com?showTable=True`.

Then look for that url parameter on the new page and only open if it's there and True.

`example-link.com#rebozo?showTable=True`

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const product = urlParams.get('showTable')
if (showTable && showTable === 'True') {
    // code to open the table
}
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/

Comment: Any clue doing this ? I'm better at swift 
I already have an anchor on this link to reach to specific card : #rebozo. So when i clik on the link, the url is domaine.com/doula/#rebozo

Comment: @Johann8724 I edited my answer with what I think it would look like

Comment: I've checked your comment and the link you gave me. 
Thank you so much because you inspired me and I was able to find. I will put the answer 